# Why specified field in InfluxDB is not being fetched?

Tags: influxdb, influxql

I come from an SQL server background and am very new to InfluxDB. I am wondering what could be a possible reason for a select command to not return any result when a **field name** is supplied instead of '*'.

> select "verb" from "Report" where "status" = 'pass'

But when I execute the following command where instead of field name I supplied *, it works.

> select * from "Report" where "status" = 'pass'

**InfluxDB shell version: 1.8.1.0**

Here's the screenshot.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Could you try the latest version, i.e. **v1.8.10**?

Both queries work there.

[image]

Not sure how your schema is.
If you didn't use any tag when inserting the data. The line protocol would be:

```
INSERT Report status="pass",failes=0,totalverbs=5,verb="Test1"
```

If you use status as the tag (note the space and comma m and no quote around "pass" below):

```
INSERT Report,status="pass" failes=0,totalverbs=5,verb="Test1"
```

Both queries work in this case as well:

[image]